# Generate subarray with equal number elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code that will generate a multidimensional array from a csv file. I need to generate a similar array with the equal number of subarray. the content of the first array will be splitted into chunks and is the csv content, the second array needs to be filled with random numbers. 
I'm using this code, but I'm only able to generate an array that will contain only 156 random numbers and this isn't what I need. How I can generate an array with 156 subarray composed from 8 numbers each?
Here is my code:

```
foreach( $csv->getRecords() as $records){
  unset($records['nux']);
  foreach (array_chunk($records, 8) as $record) {
    $nSamples[] = $record;
    $nLabels[] = 'vc';
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($nSamples); $i++ ){
      $lSamples[$i] = mt_rand(1,90);
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Here is an example of the two array, I need that the second array is similar to the first:

Random number array:

```
array(156) {
  [0]=>
  array(156) {
    [0]=>
    int(20)
    [1]=>
    int(84)
    [2]=>
    int(17)
    [3]=>
    int(64)
    [4]=>
    int(86)
    [5]=>
    int(17)
    [6]=>
    int(66)
    [7]=>
    int(35)
    [8]=>
    int(59)
    [9]=>
    int(54)
    [10]=>
    int(87)
...
```

Correct array:

```
array(156) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "19"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "26"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "44"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "61"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "89"
    [6]=>
    string(2) "84"
    [7]=>
    string(2) "64"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "19"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "28"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "43"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "58"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "82"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [7]=>
    string(2) "18"
  }
```

To reply to the comments, the 156 is not hardcoded but it's the number of the csv records.

Comment: Where is 156 in this code? Why are you overwriting `$lSamples` for each record in The CSV?

Comment: We need more data here - but my guess you need a new array in the inner `for` loop as `$a[] = mt_rand(1,90);` and after the loop `$lSamples[] = $a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the random numbers are not related to the CSV file, you can do this all outside the loop that reads the CSV. Just use nested loops:

```
$lSamples = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 156; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
        $lSamples[$i][] = mt_rand(1, 90);
    }
}
```

If it's actually supposed to be 8 random numbers for each row of the CSV, not 156 hard-coded, then just put the inner loop inside the `foreach()` loop.

```
$lSamples = [];
foreach( $csv->getRecords() as $i => $records){
  unset($records['nux']);
  foreach (array_chunk($records, 8) as $record) {
    $nSamples[] = $record;
    $nLabels[] = 'vc';
    for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
      $lSamples[$i][] = mt_rand(1, 90);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing the 156 coming from the csv get records and it cannot br hard coded

Comment: Perhaps. I couldn't figure that out, since 156 is not a multiple of 8.

Comment: @Barmar the 156 is the total number of records.

Comment: @Barmar your solution is working perfectly. I didn't considered to use the foreach index key to achieve the scope.